# Same jQuery event, separate function

Tags: jquery, html, events

Say that I have a function that needs to execute on `$(document).mousemove()`. Then I decide I have another function that needs to execute on the same event. Perhaps these two functions are unrelated, so in the name of modularity, one could have two separate functions listening for `$(document).mousemove()`.

Is this bad form? Are there performance implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery will automatically append events to a chain, so there is no problem with having duplicate handler definitions for the same event. If you can combine two handler definitions into one reasonably then there's certainly nothing wrong with that approach, but there's little explicit value in doing so other than, perhaps, readability.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply do this?  Unless I am misunderstanding your question

```
$(document).mousemove(function(){
    callOneFunction();
    callTwoFunction();
});
```

Comment: indeed i could do that, that was my question... :)

Comment: As Nathan Taylor points out in his response, jQuery will append the events in a chain.  I prefer this method as its clear what functions are being called and in what order.  Especially if others will be reading your code (I work on a team projects, so having event handlers for the same event all over the place would drive people nuts) :)

Comment: Yep this is definitely true. Thanks for the response. I should start writing functions that get called from within the event, as opposed to having the code directly in the event.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you decide to set 1000 functions listening one event i would say something wrong with your design, but for me two funcs are just ok

I would go with namespaced handlers in order to keep maintainability, at least if Saint John designed it in jQuery it worth using in some cases
so
you do this:

```
$(elem).bind('mousemove.ns1', funcOne);
$(elem).bind('mousemove.ns2', funcTwo);
```

this way you are able unbind one by one as well

```
$(elem).unbind('mousemove.ns1');
$(elem).unbind('mousemove.ns2');
```

Or even

```
$(elem).unbind('.ns1');
```